# wrapping loadFBX promise in observable using rxjs

Tags: angular, three.js, rxjs

I am trying to load an fbx file using threejs. However, I have no way of knowing when a mesh has been loaded except for the onLoad callback. so I wanted to use an observable. I have found that Rxjs 'from' seems to have a functionality to load a fromPromise (but wrapped in from).

```js
    load( url: string, onLoad: ( object: Group ) => void, onProgress?: ( event: ProgressEvent ) => void, onError?: ( event: ErrorEvent ) => void ) : void;
```

```js
    loadFBX = (fileName: string) => {
        MeshLoader.loader.load('../../assets/meshes/' + fileName + '.FBX', (object: THREE.Group) => {
        });
    }
```

```js
    this.d = from(this.meshLoader.loadFBX('polyhedronDivided'));
    this.d = from(new FBXLoader().load('../../assets/meshes/' + 'polyhedronDivided' + '.FBX', () => {}));
```

Neither of these assignments is valid. I am getting:
`ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.` I thought I was providing a promise to that function... I don't know where I am going wrong with this one...

UPDATE: changing my loadFBX function to return an observable seems to do the trick, but I don't know how that observable can be created and returned...

Answer (score 0):

Saving the data to a behaviorsubject seems to get the required result.

```js
    data = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);

    loadFBX = (fileName: string) => {
        MeshLoader.loader.load('../../assets/meshes/' + fileName + '.FBX', 
        (object: THREE.Group) => {
            this.data.next(object);
        });
    }
```

And than you can subscribe like this, which will return the object when its done loading. The filter just makes sure the code doesn't execute if the subject is undefined.

```js
    this.meshLoader.data.pipe(
      filter(x => x),
      tap(x => { console.log(x); }))
      .subscribe();
```